# Можно ли из приложения на Framework 4 использовать библиотеку Framework 4,5

Tags: c#, .net

Допустим, есть ПК с Framework 4.5 и есть приложение, которое написано под 4,0.

Данное приложение расширяемое.

Возможна ли корректная работа такого приложения, если подсунуть ему DLL, которая будет собрано под 4,5?

Собственно, столкнулся с тем, что приложение собранное под 4,0 смогло работать с AngleSharp, который собран по 4,5. На машине пользователя стоял 4,5 фреймфорк . Не почудилось ли мне это? Всегда думал, что младший не может использовать функционал старшего.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Коль скоро ваше приложение запускается под .NET 4.5, то вы можете загружать сборки, собранные под 4.5, и они будут работать корректно, вне зависимости от того, использованы ли в них фичи, которых не было в .NET 4.0. Потому что весь код -- и вашего приложения, и сторонней сборки -- будет работать под .NET 4.5.

Answer (score 1):

.NET Framework версии 4.5 был выпущен в таком виде, что обновление до этой версии с версии 4.0 можно было выполнить просто заменив все dll файлы. Более того, Ваше приложение даже не заметит подмены - сборки 4.5 определяются так же, как и сборки 4.0
Попробуйте выполнить следующий код в приложении с разными .NET Framework.

```
Console.WriteLine(Environment.Version.Major);
Console.WriteLine(Environment.Version.Build);
```

Для обоих версий (4.0 и 4.5) вывод будет:

```
4
30319
```

Касательно Вашего вопроса, приложение будет работать стабильно, Майкрософт гарантирует полную обратную совместимость с версией 4.0 для версии 4.5, Вам даже подменять ничего не нужно.

Comment: Т.е можно наружу отправить методы и классы, которые поддерживает 4,0, а внутри самой сборки работать даже с async/await ?

Comment: *"пока не встретит чего-то совсем новое, чего нет в .NET Framework 4.0"* -- неверно.

Comment: @andreycha Вы правы, я невнимательно прочитал вопрос, решил что на целевом ПК установлен .NET Framework 4.0

Comment: Сборка 4.5 в принципе не загрузится в .NET 4.0.

Comment: @andreycha Правильно ли я понимаю что Вы утверждаете, что невозможно загрузить сборку 4.5 из 4.0 приложения? С этим я готов поспорить.

Comment: Да. CLR 4.0 не загрузит сборку, скомпилированную под 4.5.

Comment: @andreycha, я вот тоже в это не верил, пока не столкнулся с этим в живую. Приложение собранное под 4,0, смогло загрузить AngleSharp 4,5 и работать. Правда, у тех у кого не стоял на ПК 4,5 она не работало, а вот у остальных работало. Поэтому собственно решил переспросить тут.

Comment: @Geslot автоматическая полная обратная совместимость не гарантируется - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh367887(v=vs.110).aspx - есть поведение, которое поменяется после установки 4.5, причем некоторые вещи (вроде  проблем с SoapFormatter) на старое поведение переключить нельзя

Comment: @iluxa1810 4.5 заменяет 4.0. Ваше приложение, собранное под 4.0, работало под 4.5.

Comment: @iluxa1810 ну так о том и речь. Нет CLR 4.5 -- не будут работать сборки, собранные под 4.5. И неважно, под какую платформу было собрано само приложение.

Comment: @Geslot На чём основаны ваши утверждения "
голос «за»
1
голос «против»
.NET Framework версии 4.5 был выпущен в таком виде, что обновление до этой версии с версии 4.0 можно было выполнить просто заменив все dll файлы.", "Майкрософт гарантирует полную обратную совместимость с версией 4.0 для версии 4.5"?

Comment: @Geslot "Более того, Ваше приложение даже не заметит подмены - сборки 4.5 определяются так же, как и сборки 4.0" Это неправда. Просто это надо определять другим способом.